# same css style in div, label and button but button height is shorter

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.before {
  font-size: 11pt;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

label {
  padding: 4px 11px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

label>input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: inherit;
  outline: none;
}

button {
  font-size: 11pt;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="IdontWannaSetThisDiv" style="font-size: 0">
  <div class="before">
    <span>https://</span>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <button>
    <span>.com</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I've used 3 tags `div`, `label`, and `button`.

And I've given them same `CSS` style `padding: 4px 11px` and `font-size: 11pt`.

I expected them who has the same height but the only button is different.

I want to make them as same height without a `height` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<button>` has a different font than the other fields, therefore, the text is rendered smaller.

Apply `font-family: initial;` to the `<button>` so it uses the same font:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.before {
  font-size: 11pt;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

label {
  padding: 4px 11px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

label>input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: inherit;
  outline: none;
}

button {
  font-family: initial;   /* <-- */
  font-size: 11pt;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="IdontWannaSetThisDiv" style="font-size: 0">
  <div class="before">
    <span>https://</span>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <button>
    <span>.com</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use DISPLAY:FLEX; on its parent, and its done, they all will take the equal height.

Do read it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.IdontWannaSetThisDiv {display: flex;}

.before {
  font-size: 11pt;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

label {
  padding: 4px 11px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

label>input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: inherit;
  outline: none;
}

button {
  font-size: 11pt;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="IdontWannaSetThisDiv" style="font-size: 0">
  <div class="before">
    <span>https://</span>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <button>
    <span>.com</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: good try. Thank you for your answer. but I don't want to use `flex`.  :)

Comment: That's completely OK, but you did not mention it in your Question so, anyway, enjoy

Comment: I did. look at the parent's class name.